# anchorscroll does not navigate to div perfectly in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

My code is as shown below:

xyz.html

```
<div class="q-filters" sticky offset="25">
        <a style="text-decoration:none;margin-bottom:10px;color:black;" href="" ng-click="gotoDiv(menu.name)" style="margin-bottom:10px;" ng-repeat="menu in menuItems" class='q-filter q-recommended'>{{menu.name}}</a>

    </div>

    <div class="q-menu" ng-repeat="menu in menuItems" ng-if="menu.isVisible">
        <div id="anchor{{menu.name}}" class="q-head anchor"><span>{{menu.name}}</span></div>
    <div class="q-list" ng-repeat="item in menu.items" ng-class="{'active':item.addClicked}">

</div>
```

xyz.js

```
 $scope.gotoDiv = function(x) {
                var newHash = 'anchor' + x;
                if ($location.hash() !== newHash) {
                    $location.hash('anchor' + x);
                } else {
                    $anchorScroll();
                }
            };
```

I have followed the code given [here](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/angularjs-scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-anchorscrollexample.html)

But somehow it does not land to the div perfectly. For more details the demo is shown [here](http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/demo/demo-angularjs-scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-anchorscrollexample.html#/anchor2#anchor1)

Now, how to make it work?

Comment: your demo seems to work fine.

Comment: In my case ,when I click on the link given in `q-list`, it goes and stop at the items inside `q-list`, rather than div with anchor .

Comment: Even in the demo mentioned ,it does not stop at the text `div x of the 5 element`. Instead it stops at the deep level of that div